# In Corda, NoClassDefFoundError: SimpleFieldAccess error when running deployNodes

Tags: corda

In Corda 3, I am receiving the following error when I run the `deployNodes` task:

> java.io.NotSerializableException: Unexpected throwable: net/corda/nodeapi/internal/serialization/carpenter/SimpleFieldAccess java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/corda/nodeapi/internal/serialization/carpenter/SimpleFieldAccess

My Java version is as follows:

```
java version “1.8.0_161”
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_161-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.161-b12, mixed mode)
```

What is the cause of this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a JRE installed, instead of a JDK. Please install version 8u131+ of the Oracle JDK 8 JVM. You can find it here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html.